In flutter ternary operator is not working properly?
Code snippet 1:
 factory Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Weather(
      sunrise: json['daily']['sunrise'][0].split('T')[1],
      sunset: json['daily']['sunset'][0].split('T')[1],
      temp: json['current']['temperature_2m'].toString(),
      wind: json['current']['wind_speed_10m'].toString(),
      day: json['current']['is_day'] ? 'Morning' : 'Night',
      time: json['current']['time'].split('T')[1],
    );
  }

Code snippet 2:
final Weather? weather;

final ThemeData selectedTheme =
        ((weather?.day ?? 'Morning') == 'Morning') ? lightTheme : darkTheme;

the condition always evaluates to 0 and there is always darkTheme in my app.
how do I solve this?

can you please show the material app code where the theme applies?

Are you sure weather?.day is not 'Night'. Try printing weather.day. Please edit the question with the result if the issue persists.

Can you share your entire model class for Weather? also the json you are receiving from the API response.
My hypothesis is that you must have taken day as nullable variable and it must be storing null value which might happen because of json structure or key you are using is not correct.
So here when you'll have null stored in day variable, you will always have dark there as per your usage in selectedTheme code.


try printing selectedTheme
try changing the code into if else block.

